# Is there a C client demo program for comunicating with ROS server?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All.
Is there a C client program that can make me send and receive information from ROS server?
What I need it is that I want to use C program to develop some program and use it as a client of ROS server.
Best regards.
Zhenli
zhenli.lu@ua.pt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12827/is-there-a-c-client-demo-program-for-comunicating-with-ros-server?/) by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-01-31

Post score: -2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this tutorial:

[Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B))

It goes over writing a pair of minimal c++ programs that send each other a message using the ROS interface

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3